# What's wrong with my assembly code

Tags: assembly, x86

I'm trying to write a factorial code in assembly using jmp and jz and i'm new to assembly

input should be eax and the output is ebx

```
    mov eax,3h ;factorial of 3
    ;initialize registers
    mov ebx,0h
    mov ecx,eax
    dec ecx
    mov edx,0h

loopstart:
    mul ecx ;edx:eax = eax * ecx
    add ebx,eax ;ebx = ebx + eax
    dec ecx ;ecx = ecx - 1
    jz exitloop ;jump to exitloop if the last math is zero ( in this ex:dec)
    jmp loopstart ;jump to loopstart
exitloop:
    ;mov eax,ebx
    call ebxprint; should be 6
```

Find factorial of eax

input: 2

output: 2

input: 3

output: 12

input: 4

output: 60

So, What's the problem here?

Comment: Describe actual output, comment your code and learn to use a debugger. Hint: there is no addition in factorial, why do you have one?

Comment: Why are you repeatedly adding the partially computed factorials to `ebx`? I think you want to remove the `add ebx, eax` instruction, and to add `mov ebx, eax` where you currently have the commented out `; mov eax, ebx` after `exitloop`.

Comment: @PaulHankin Thanks

Comment: You are not stuck at the "writing assembly" phase, you are stuck at the "designing the algorithm" phase. I find it often helps to write out the algorithm in pseudo-code first. I like to do it on paper, just to get a completely different (non-computer) feel. Then, I'll translate that pseudo-code into assembly instructions.

Comment: @CodyGray Thanks, I'll do that next time

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to @PaulHankin

I must remove `add ebx, eax` and uncomment `mov eax,ebx`

Here is the code after editing:

```
    mov eax,3h ;factorial of 3
    ;initialize registers
    mov ebx,0h
    mov ecx,eax
    dec ecx
    mov edx,0h

loopstart:
    mul ecx ;edx:eax = eax * ecx
    dec ecx ;ecx = ecx - 1
    jz exitloop ;jump to exitloop if the last math is zero ( in this ex:dec)
    jmp loopstart ;jump to loopstart
exitloop:
    mov eax,ebx
    call ebxprint; should be 6
```